# How to fix Registry update failed on OpenShift to install Phoenix depedencies?

Tags: openshift, elixir, phoenix-framework

Does anyone know how to fix this issue with deploying Phoenix on OpenShift?

This happens when I run `mix deps.get`:

```
Registry update failed (http_error)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :eacces}]}
** (Mix) Failed to fetch registry
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to `repo.hex.pm` from the server? (`curl https://repo.hex.pm/registry.ets.gz | wc -c` should succeed and return a number around 750000.)

Comment: Yes. It works:  ```% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  728k  100  728k    0     0  4262k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11.6M
745796```

Comment: It may be related to this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/MX0ayxrI2Tw

Comment: Could you try running this in `erl`: `inets:start(), ssl:start(), httpc:request(get, {"https://repo.hex.pm/registry.ets.gz", []}, [{timeout, 60000}], []).`? If you get the same error, this looks like an Erlang bug to me.

Comment: OpenShift is going through some necessary maintenance. I could not check now. Probably a bug, but it may also be an OpenShift issue.

Comment: It didn't work on OpenShift: `{error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{"repo.hex.pm",443}}, {inet,[inet],eacces}]}}`. I tried it locally. It works of course. How can it be an Erlang bug if I use the same version on my Mac and on OpenShift? It is probably a networking issue. I could report to OpenShift now.